# How to Pause and Resume the Task which runs Asynchronously

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, asynchronous, async-await

I have a long running code, which i want pause resume functionality. In the start method am writing my code and starting the new async task. But i want this task to be paused/resumed on demand.

```
  var myTask;
  public void start()
    {
        myTask = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
         ///my business logic
        });
    }
```

Comment: Is your code doing a loop or something?

Comment: Task scheduling is cooperative. To pause a task, you need to use some means of communicating this to it; for example, by setting a sentinel flag. However, it will be up to the task to observe and honour the flag. If you want preemptive scheduling (where you can force one to pause), you'll need to revert to threads. Note that even threads cannot be paused when they're executing native calls.

Comment: Learn from the best. Here's Stephen Toub's take on the problem: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2013/01/13/cooperatively-pausing-async-methods.aspx

Comment: I'm confused, you tagged this C# 4.0, but also `async`-`await`, which is a C# 5.0 feature. So which is it?

Comment: sorry svick (:  it is not async-await, just C# 4.0 TPL feature

Comment: Update to link provided by @KirillShlenskiy - https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/cooperatively-pausing-async-methods/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to be aware of the differences between a Task and a Thread. A Task is something you want to be done. A thread is one of the many possible workers which performs that task. Separate tasks don't have to be performed by separate threads. The same thread can perform several Tasks. One task might be performed by several threads.

If you want a level of control where you want to be able to halt a running task for a while at any moment, regardless of what it is doing right now, consider using a thread. Be aware that when you halt a thread for a while it will be holding the scarce resources it might use at that moment.

Therefore it might be wiser to only hold your process at certain pre-defined points of execution. In that case a Task might be a wiser choice.

By using a Task you express that you don't want to be bothered with who is doing the execution, therefore you can't control the executioner. In fact, by using a task you express that you even don't care if your complete process is handled by one thread or multiple threads.

If you want to halt execution of your process at certain defined points in the process consider dividing the task into sub-tasks, each sub-task ending at a point where you would want the process to halt. By using Task.ContinueWith you can decide when the task should continue processing the next step of the process.

The neat solution would be to wrap your process (or task) into a class where users of the class could say: run until step X is performed, or: run until state Y is reached. This way the users of the class wouldn't even have to know whether your process is run using a Task or a Thread.

Comment: Can you provide an example of a thread API capable of "halting a running task for a while at any moment, regardless of what it is doing right now" please?

Comment: @KirillShlenskiy [`System.Threading.Thread.Suspend()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.suspend(v=vs.110).aspx), however that method is marked obsolete and it really recommends you use the other method of putting in "checkpoints" where you could pause the execution using a Semaphore, Mutex, or some other logic.

Comment: I quite agree: don't suspend at any moment. You don't know what the thread is doing, at the moment you suspend, so you can't be sure what the suspender is allowed to do. Besides I wonder if it is really necessary to  halt the other task immediately.

Answer (score 4):

Well, you can create your own simple task scheduler and from inside of the task check for current task status repeatedly. To make it thread safe we would need to mark our bool flags as `volatile`:

```
class MySimpleTaskScheduler
{
   private volatile bool isPaused;
   private volatile bool isStopped;
   private Task _myBackgroundTask;

   public void StartTask()
   {
       _myBackgroundTask = new Task.Run(() => 
       {
          while(!isStopped)
          {
             while(!isPaused && !isStopped)
             {
                .. do something
                Thread.Sleep(100);  // set some delay before check if task is set on pause
             }

             Thread.Sleep(100);  // set some timeout before check if task is stopped              }
       });
   }

   public void Pause()
   {
      isPaused = true;     
   }

   public void Resume()
   {
      isPaused = false;         
   }

   public void Stop()
   {
      isPaused = true;       
      isStopped = true;       
   }
}
```